# Como alterar o estilo de um elemento em um iframe a partir da página mãe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Utilizo um componente que gera um `iframe` acessando uma página remota.

Exemplo: supondo que no `iframe` exista uma tabela com alguns `TDs` com a classe `destaque`, quero colocar uma borda vermelha nestes "destaques".

Tentei o seguinte código, mas não funciona:

```
$('iframe tr td.destaque').css('border-color', 'red');
```

**Como alterar o estilo de um elemento em um `iframe` a partir da página mãe?**

**UPDATE:** Tentando utilizar o `contents`, conforme resposta de @Rafalages, apresenta o seguinte erro:

> jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://192.168.1.15" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Answer (score 1):

.contents() deve resolver:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('tr td.destaque').css('border-color', 'red');
```

https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: Agora apresenta o erro: jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://192.168.1.15" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: Cara, a página tem que estar no mesmo domínio que o seu ou então estar com CORS ativo.

Comment: Se estiver em outro domínio e não estiver com o CORS ativo?